# Setting environment variables in Django site on Nginx server

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have a Django site on an Ubuntu VPS running Nginx. I wanted to secure my postgres password and Django secret key and followed this guide to do so:

https://ultimatedjango.com/learn-django/lessons/handling-sensitive-keys/

afterwards nothing seemed to break on the site and I could still make changes and view everything so I assumed it had all worked.

I have since then noticed that when I first login to the server I get this warning about the Django secret key added in my .bashrc file:

```
-bash: /home/david/.bashrc: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
-bash: /home/david/.bashrc: line 19: `export SECRET_KEY=2nv#wlp)3h-p32y-hidden-rest-of-key-for-secruity'
```

so I guess this is happening because I didn't add the key as a string? If so why is the site still running esp. when I didnt add the postgres password as a string either?

Also if I try to run any kind of migrations now I get this message:

```
  File "/home/david/myproj/myproj/settings.py", line 21, in <module>
    CRMEASY_DB_PASS = get_env_variable('CRMEASY_DB_PASS')
NameError: name 'get_env_variable' is not defined
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this counts as the 'answer' to this but I removed and then re-installed uwsgi and then removed all the passwords and keys from .bashrc and put them back into the settings file and seems to be working now.